# Uniform Convergence of Lagrange function defined for $q-$absolutely continuous curves

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, semicontinuous-functions

In my course on Nonlinear PDEs, we investigate the integral functional
$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} L(\dot{\gamma}(t), \gamma(t))dt$, defined on $q$-absolutely continuous curves $\gamma: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with some interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}.$ They form a Banach space, denoted as $AC^q(I)$ and defined as in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity, but with the requirement that the weak derivative is in $L^q(I)$ where $q\geq 1.$

We require that the Lagrange function $L$ is:

$ \bullet L \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$

$ \bullet v \mapsto L(v,x)$ is convex for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n $

$ \bullet |L(v,x)| \leq A |v|^q + B $ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n,v \in \mathbb{R}^n $ (continuity)

$\bullet |L(v,x)| \geq \alpha |v|^q - \beta $ (coercivity)

where $\alpha \geq 0, \beta \geq 0, A$ and $B$ constants.

**Now the question.** **We have the claim:**

If $(\gamma_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset  AC^q(I)$ converges uniformly to $ \gamma^* \in AC^q(I)$ on $I , \dot{\gamma}^*$ bounded on a subinterval $J \subset I,$ then the continuity of $L$ yields that $L(\dot{\gamma}^*(t), \gamma_k(t))$ converges uniformly to $L(\dot{\gamma}^*(t), \gamma^*(t))$ for $t \in J.$

**Could anyone please provide details on the reasoning?** Apologies if it is something very obvious.